# Drop-down box in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have one asp.net c# grid-view.
This gridview requires dropdown box and drop-down box's selected data will come from database.
Please help me for this.

Comment: have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

In that case, firstly populate the required data/fields on to the dropdownlist and in the dropdownlist_SelectedIndexChanged, make sure you write the code for populating the data in the GridView with your required with where clause specified; the where clause need to make use of the data selected in the dropdown list.. :)

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: Hi Vidhya,Thanks for your revert.Basically i am able to populate data.Only thing is that i can not able to select data on dropdown those are coming from database for respective rows.

Comment: basically i wanted selected value in dropdown from database at the page load for each row of gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Not heaps clear on your question - some code snippets or a thorough description would be more useful. But I will soldier on!

You can convert any field in an ASP.NET GridView into a Template Field by selecting 'Edit Columns' on the Smart Tag. The Template Field will allow you to specify a control(s) to put inside that grid cell **instead of** a standard text box. You can bind it to whatever data source you like (or even bind the data source to the parent row). I suggest you google 'Grid View Template Field' for more thorough information about how to get it done.